# Get Keyboard input with Java while windows doesn't have focus?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

I'm trying to create a simple java program, is there anyway so that even if the application doesn't have focus and a person hits a key, to do an event?

Ex.  Program does no have focus and you want to quickly bring it to focus with control + i

Is there anyway that without the window having focus, I can read what is happening with the keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

```
Is there anyway that without the window having focus
```

no, not possible directly, but then we talking about `KeyLogger`, and `KeyLoger` is `AntiVirus` relevant

if some Java `Window` has focus in the screen then you can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)